# Is this an example of a proxy pattern, or a decorator pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I find myself using the following design more and more frequently, and my gut says this is a type of proxy since I'm not really adding much functionality. The only reason I doubt it is because the code tends to more resemble the decorator examples I see!

What do you think?

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
}

class PersonProxyOrDecarator : Person
{
    private Lazy<string> _address;
    public PersonProxyOrDecarator(PersonRepository repository)
    {                
        _address = new Lazy<string>(()=> repository.LoadAddress(this));
    }

    public override string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _address.Value;
        }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}

class PersonRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> LoadPeople()
    {
        return new List<Person>(){
            new PersonProxyOrDecarator(this){ Name="Test",Age=18 }
        };
    }
    public string LoadAddress(Person person)
    {
        return "Address loaded from webservice";
    }
}
```

Not that it matters but the person entity class would normally sit in a different assembly (a domain assembly), and the personproxyordecorator class and the repository would sit in an assembly repository.

Thanks

Ross

Comment: To me, it's a proxy. To be a decorator, I would expect it to add and/or change functionality to the `LoadAddress` method whereas your implemenation only delays the actual retrieval of the adress which is a typical proxy property.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's both. Technically deriving that class from Person makes it Decorator, but since you are having some loading logic behind it is also a Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is neither Proxy nor Decorator because these patterns require an object to be wrapped, not only subclassed. A Proxy or Decorator class uses both inheritance (ProxyPerson *is-a* Person) and composition (ProxyPerson *has-a* Person). PersonProxyOrDecarator doesn't have a Person field so it doesn't control/decorate a Person object, rather it is a (subclassed) Person object. Proxy is a special case of Decorator.

For some background on these patterns see [Decorator](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DecoratorPattern) and [Proxy](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProxyPattern).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get a simple answer out of this one - but it makes for an interesting discussion.

**Is it a Proxy?**  To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern), a proxy class:

> is a class functioning as an interface to something else.

Sufficiently vague, but is certainly satisfied by your example - your inherited class acts as a gateway to the `Person` class.  However, this "universal" definition of proxy seems to fit every class you could ever write as a developer, so I'm not sure how useful it is without some context (for example if I talk about service within a Service-Orientated Application context the term proxy becomes more meaningful).

**Is it a Decorator?**  Yes!  Your inherited class adds extra decoration to the `Address` property (it won't let you set it).

Let us throw another one in to the mix - I suggest it is also a **Factory** - since you are "hydrating" the properties of the Person interface from within the inherited class.